# Knockout add rows to table insert button and image

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have the following sample code:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fXr8x/)

I'm trying to insert rows to a table using knockout. I generate random values using chance.js.

I'm using observable array and computed for my date. The computed is used to combine the url of an image. There are three images `flag_red.png`, `flag_green.png` and `flag_yellow.png`.

I define the path to the image in a variable `var photoPath = "..Images/flag_"`

the values red, green and yellow are randomly selected from an array and the computed field will make the whole path to a random image (red, green, yellow)

Example: `../Images/flag_green.png`

The last two columns are used for image and last one for a button with drop down.

Comment: P.S. I solved the button, I was using text instead of html binding ... however the image is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: results().statusImage }" alt="" height="16" width="16" />
```

correct would be:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: statusImage }" alt="" height="16" width="16" />
```

Hint: You *already are* inside a `foreach`.

Comment: Strange thing though that you defined your `btn` as a huge string of HTML instead of simply using a knockout template. That would be nicer, more idiomatic (no layout in the code!) and more flexible.

Comment: aaaa okey ? Sounds better but i'm just starting with knockout. Any hints how to achieve that ?

Comment: So basically what you mean is I can wrap the button declaration into a script template and just bind that template for each row in table? Did i understood it right?